# How does redux-saga handle callback?

Tags: redux-saga

I am learning Redux-Saga. I am trying to send a request then call a method to do something in my component. Below is my code:

```js
function* getLeftCount({ payload: { query, callBackFun } }) {
  const data = yield call (apiService.getLeftCount, query);
  callBackFun (data.data.result);
}
```

then i will use `takeLatest()` to add it to saga.

however, it has an issue: if there are multiple same components and send requests at the same time. only one will get the callback work fine, others won't receive a callback.

if I use `takeEvery()`, it will work fine but send duplicated requests and cause waste.

are there any best practices to handle this scenario？

Comment: can you define "if I use takeEvery(), it will work fine but send duplicated requests and cause waste." in more elaborated way. what is the expected behaviour here? and in what do you mean by duplicated request?